# C++ ODBC Unhandled exception / Access violation writing location

Tags: c++, sql, exception, odbc, runtime-error

I am writing a ODBC-database class which contains a member function used to fetch a series of attributes and tuples from a given query.

I have a single line of code in the statements below which causes this runtime error to be throw in debug mode:

```
Unhandled exception at <mem loc> in <prog name>: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location <mem loc>.
```

and here is the code where `ERROR` points out the offending line:

```
SQLINTEGER length = 0;
vector<vector<string>> data;
this->sReturn = SQLFetch(this->sHandle);

while (this->sReturn == SQL_SUCCESS) {
  vector<string> tuple;

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
  SQLPOINTER value = "";

  switch (info[i].columnType) {
    case 0 : //SQL_UNKNOWN_TYPE
      throw DatabaseAttributeTypeUnknown("The database returned an attribute of an unknown type.");
      break;

    case 1 : //SQL_CHAR
      this->sReturn = SQLGetData(this->sHandle, i + 1, info[i].columnType, value,
        info[i].columnSize*sizeof(SQLCHAR),
ERROR   &length);
        break;

     //Some more cases
  }
}
```

Any idea on why this error is being thrown? Here is the [MSDN documentation on SQLGetData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is assigning a value to `length`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a compiler maps executable code to line of code in the sources, they generally cannot differentiate lines in a statement that is split into multiple lines. So if the debugger says that an error happens on a specific line, it can actually be anywhere in the entire statement, so somewhere in:

```
this->sReturn = SQLGetData(this->sHandle, i + 1, info[i].columnType, value,
    info[i].columnSize*sizeof(SQLCHAR),
    &length);
```

The only shaky pointer here is `value` which point to a null static string, so to a one character long array containing a null byte. Also, depending on compiler options, this array can be in a read-only segment of data. While SQLGetData() thinks it points to a location which is at least `info[i].columnSize*sizeof(SQLCHAR)` bytes in size and where it will write (not read) the data from the SQL column.

I may miss other details, but my first guess is that is what causes the memory access violation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Frederic said. Are you compiling your code 64 bit? If so you'll find SQLGetData takes a pointer to an SQLLEN for the last argument not an SQLINTEGER:

```
SQLRETURN  SQL_API SQLGetData(SQLHSTMT StatementHandle,
                              SQLUSMALLINT ColumnNumber, SQLSMALLINT TargetType,
                              SQLPOINTER TargetValue, SQLLEN BufferLength,
                              SQLLEN *StrLen_or_Ind);
```

An SQLLEN is 8 bytes in 64 bit windows not 4 bytes as SQLINTEGER is.